# Updating MySQL with data from MS SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

**In MySQL is it possible to execute an update query with values selected from external MS SQL database?**

I would like to execute every night a timed query, which updates some the data in MySQL with data on MS SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Typically how you would do this is, create a SSIS package (dts) that pulls the data in and does anything else you want to do. Then setup a SQL job to run the package, then Setup a A SQL batch to kick off the job whenever you want it to run